# '"media_edit_action" plugin does not exist' error when performing update

Tags: updating

I get the following error after a database update. It looks like it completes the update by displaying *Completed 8 of 8* but it doesn't run the updates. Any help is appreciated.

> Failed: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "media_edit_action" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of /srv/bindings/ae21023ced6d43099409c0fbbeded25e/code/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

This is what the updates need to run.

#### System module

> Change plugin IDs of actions.
>   Clear caches due to schema changes in core.entity.schema.yml.

#### Views module

> Update dependencies for moved bulk field plugin.
>   Add additional settings to the entity link field and convert node_path usage to entity_link.
>   Add placeholder settings to string or numeric filters. 
>   Fix cache max age for table displays.
>   Include views data table provider in views dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that action at some point became deprecated and was removed from the [media_entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity).  However, the configuration lingered and is blocking Drupal update from completing successfully.

What worked for me was to go the the `Admin > Configuration > Development > Configuration Synchronization > Updates Report` (menu tab).

If you view the Full Report, then you can see that the config for the `media_edit_action` is still present.

Use the pulldown menu on the right to delete that config.

[image: Delete the media_edit_action config]

When you run update again, then it should complete successfully.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank Rich, it worked. I just needed to install the Config_update module in order for the Updates Report tab to show up. https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/config_update-8.x-1.5.tar.gz